# Display two ID from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a query like this one below :

```
    $request = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles, cities WHERE cities.city = :current_city AND articles.idtitle = :idtitle');
    $request->execute(array('current_city' => $current_city, 'idtitle' => $_GET['title']));
    $data = $request->fetch();
    $request->closeCursor();
```

But when I'm trying to `echo $data['ID']` it displays the ID from the table cities. Is there a way to differentiate both ID ? 
Something like `$data['articles.ID']`.

I thought of using two queries but maybe it could be done with one.

Comment: You can use Luthando Loot's answer, but honestly, you'd be better off with a `join`.

Comment: Join does not solve this problem at all. The `select *` is the "wrong" part - you should always list all columns you need - that way you can assign aliases directly where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to look like:

```
'SELECT articles.ID  AS Article_ID,cities.ID AS City_ID,cities.*, articles.*   
FROM articles, cities 
WHERE cities.city = :current_city AND articles.idtitle = :idtitle'
```

Then in your php:

```
echo $data['Article_ID'];
echo $data['City_ID'];
```

Comment: `*` won't work, you need to specify the tables, so you'd have `cities.*, articles.*`

Comment: Cheers, dunno why you're being downvoted though. This is a legit answer.

Comment: It's also worth nothing that the query will bring up 4 ids. The aliases and the actual ids since you're doing `*`. This is more of a warning to OP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score -1):

> maybe it could be done with one.

When having a lunch, don't you ask yourself the same question, like if it could be done in a single course - coke, burger and fries, all crushed and mixed in one bowl?